# Twilio Chat Service like WhatsApp with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, ios11, twilio-api

I have gone through Documentation and little confuse if after integration of SDK App can be work like WhatsApp! Mostly what I understand is, it is for Web to Mobile and vice versa chatting service. My confusion is, can it be made like WhatsApp? I mean chatting application, where I can chat with twilio contacts like WhatsApp contacts in iOS only for mobile app to mobile app?

Comment: Hey, not quite sure what you're asking here. The Twilio Programmable Chat  SDK allows you to build chat into your own application, across iOS, Android and web. That chat will be between the users of your application.

Comment: Hi @philnash thanks for coming, I have gone through every video of Brent’s in youtube but didn’t find any scene where Brent showing the chat thing across mobile.. anyway thanks again for clearing my confusion though..

Comment: If you implement the SDK in each of those platforms and use the same chat service, then messages can be sent from one to the other. Most of our videos and documentation deal with one platform at a time though. Hope this all helps!

Comment: @philnash my main concern is, by integrating programmable chat in my app, can it be work like WhatsApp? Suppose user A and user B using my app and can they communicate each other via chat within the app ??

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @philnash Thank you Sir .. 

Comment: @philnash how to remove badge when user seen message in swift? i search a lot in dcoumentation. is it possible to do with `TCHChannel`?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint Have you looked into updating the [user's consumption horizon](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/consumption-horizon)?

Answer (score 1):

Chat API is already used for many projects: sending and reading messages from the CRM-system, recording in the beauty salon, sending details of the vacancy or chat-bot with promotional codes.

Chat with website visitors via popular messaging apps. The "Message Us" button takes the website visitors directly to the messaging app on desktop or mobile. Get more chats and keep conversation going even if visitors leave your website.

COMMUNICATION WITH YOUR CUSTOMERS CAN BE VERY EASY AND FAST
WhatsApp Chat WP allows your customer to start a WhatsApp chat directly from your website.
Just click the button to open WhatsApp chat app with exactly contact and pre-filled message.
Fast and close answer can turn over your business and grow your results!